# How to set max length of a json file with Xampp?

Tags: php, json, xampp, web-config

I'm building a dynamic web application. But when I tryed to upload a bigger dataset, it wouldn't return anything. So I checked it out and found out that you can set the max length of a json in the `web.config`. But that is only usuable for asp.net web application. Is there anyway I can set the max lenght of a JSON within Xampp or something else?

I found this answer on stack for asp.net web applications, but mabey there's something similar I can use:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
</appSettings>
```

Changed the `php.ini` settings to this:

```
; Whether PHP will read the POST data.
; This option is enabled by default.
; Most likely, you won't want to disable this option globally. It causes $_POST
; and $_FILES to always be empty; the only way you will be able to read the
; POST data will be through the php://input stream wrapper. This can be useful
; to proxy requests or to process the POST data in a memory efficient fashion.
; http://php.net/enable-post-data-reading
enable_post_data_reading = On

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size=0
```

Comment: Hi, i think web.config is only for asp.net web application.. you are using XAMPP?

Comment: Owww oké. Is there another way I could set the max length of JSON file? Because when I checked the response of my AJAX call I saw that it would not return everything of my Json.

Comment: What is the filesize of your json object? Check php.ini and see what's the value of max_post_size. Maybe you can try increasing it

Comment: did you restart php?